# How to fill an missing values in a column based on another column

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning, dataframe

I have a dataframe called shoes

```
Brand   Comment
Ugg       NaN
Prada     NaN
Clarks    NaN
Ugg       NaN
Clark     NaN
Prada     Made from horse leather
Prada     Made from pig leather
Prada     NaN
Ugg       Made from Australian cow leather
...
```

and another dataframe df_mode which was obtained by taking the mode of the comments for each shoe brand in the shoes dataframe for nonnull values

```
Brand  Comment
Ugg    Made from sheep 
Prada  Made from pig leather
Clarks Made from Cow leather
```

How can I assign the missing values for each shoe brand in the shoes dataframe with its respective mode response shown in the df_mode dataframe.

This is basically what I'm trying to achieve

```
Brand   Comment
Ugg       Made from sheep
Prada     Made from pig leather
Clarks    Made from Cow leather
Ugg       Made from sheep
Clark     Made from Cow leather
Prada     Made from horse leather
Prada     Made from pig leather
Prada     Made from pig leather
Ugg       Made from Australian cow leather
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

shoes = pd.DataFrame({'Brand':['Ugg', 'Prada', 'Clark', 'Ugg', 'Clark'],
                     'Comment':[np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]})

df_shoes = pd.DataFrame({('Ugg','Made from sheep'),
                     ('Prada', 'Made from pig leather'),
                     ('Clark', 'Made from Cow leather')}, columns=['Brand', 'Comment'])


shoes.merge(df_shoes, on=['Brand'], how='left', suffixes=('_x', '_y'))
```

The result will show like:
[image]

You can then drop the null columns.

**EDIT:** 
As discussed in the comments, in case for the edited question, you can do that:

```
shoes[shoes.Comment.isnull()].merge(df_shoes,on=['Brand'], how='left',suffixes=('', '_notnull'))

shoes.Comment.fillna(value=temp.Comment_notnull)
```

Comment: tried this but the NaN values still seem be to present

Comment: Sorry for that, you should merge based on Brand only, try that.

Comment: I edited again the answer

Comment: Thanks again for your response. But it suggests all the elements in the comment column are empty which isn't the case. I think that's a mistake on my part. I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: Basically, What I'm trying to do is to assign  comments present in the df_mode data frame to missing comments in the shoes dataframe without having to create a new column

Comment: Humm, you could try: 
shoes['Comment'] = shoes.Comment.fillna(value=df_shoes.Comment)
shoes = shoes.sort_values(by='Brand').fillna(method='ffill')
But it is werid that you have colums with same brand and different comments.

Basically in the approach above we use df_shoes.Comment colum to fill null values, then we sort by brand and use forward fill, but check if it is normal to have different labels for same brand.

Comment: So basically, the shoes dataframe is a (6000,6) dataframe. however, the comment column contains about 500 missing values. So what I'm planning to do is to fill this missing data with the most common comment for each brand (i.e the df_shoes data which was obtained from taking the mode of the comment section of the shoes dataframe).

Comment: I don't know if that makes sense. Maybe I'm just not explaining it well haha

Comment: Ok then. I think this will work:
 - temp = shoes[shoes.Comment.isnull()].merge(df_shoes, on=['Brand'], how='left', suffixes=('', '_notnull'))
- shoes['Comment'] = shoes.Comment.fillna(value=temp.Comment_notnull)

Let me know if this works. Sorry for not getting a cleanest answered. But I cant think to do it in another way.

Comment: Oh no that's completely fine. I quite understand how challenging it can be. 
I tried out the code but I got an error message of `SyntaxError: can't assign to operator` Just came across a similar question on stackoverflow that may work. I can send you the link if you're interested

Comment: you cpy & paste ir wrong:
`shoes[shoes.Comment.isnull()].merge(df_shoes,on=['Brand'], how='left', suffixes=('', '_notnull'))`
     `shoes.Comment.fillna(value=temp.Comment_notnull)`

They are two commands. Try now, please.

Comment: It works!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need a join, check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) out, it really helped me understand how to handle situations like the one above. I know this isn't a complete answer, but going through the link is worth the time.